# My phone dials #3282 (#DATA) by itself. Which app did it?

Tags: permissions, logging, call-history

For about the last month, I occasionally find my Cricket Samsung Amp Prime (Android 7.1.1) dialing #3282 (#DATA) without me initiating it.  According to my call log, it started on October 1, 2018.  It has happened about 6 or 7 times over about five weeks, with no noticeable pattern.  It *does* seem to happen after I've been actively using the phone.  On Cricket, this results in a "Your call can not be completed as dialed" message.  I think it used to be an active feature but is no more.

I suspect that an app update is behind this, but I'm not sure which one.  I have about 20 apps with phone permission enabled.  Is there a way to log when an app uses phone privileges?  Or straighter to the point, does anyone know which app might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the app was Nova Launcher.  I had recently enabled the permissions needed for gestures, and presumably, one of the defaults is to dial #DATA when a user swipes down on the screen.

To disable this gesture, start Nova Launcher, go to **Settings**, and edit the **Swipe Down** gesture (or whichever gesture is assigned) and choose **None** or another action.